# ImportError: No module named keras.optimizers

Tags: python, keras

I have this import statement in Keras:

```
from keras.optimizers import SGD, RMSprop
```

But getting this error on this error:

```
ImportError: No module named keras.optimizers
```

Why is that? And, how can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you should follow the [installation docs](https://keras.io/#installation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most obvious answer would be: You do not have `keras` installed. Do you? Maybe try `pip install keras` or `pip freeze` to check? Or if you are on Linux, you can also try `which keras`.

Can you provide us with additional information?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are totally right. In a previous installation I realized that Keras wasn't actually installed, as I got "could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras': Permission denied". I then used "sudo pip install keras" to install Keras properly.