# .Error in importing keras.optimizers.schedules

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

---

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 from keras.optimizers import schedules

ImportError: cannot import name 'schedules' from 'keras.optimizers' (C:\Users\hp\Roaming\anaconda3-64bit\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers.py)
I have tensorflow version 1.13.1 and keras version 2.3.1 and conda version 4.6.14. I can import keras.optimizers. I can import every function in it except schedules. Even from keras.optimizers import * works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named keras.optimizers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39081910/importerror-no-module-named-keras-optimizers)

Comment: keras.optimizers exists. I can import every other module except schedules. I don't know why.

Comment: Where did you read about the schedules package? it is not part of keras, but tf.keras, which are not the same library

Answer (score 3):

Try this sequence to see if you have everything installed:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import schedules
```

if this doesn't work, also check the output of conda list:

```
(ds_tensorflow) c:\temp>conda list | grep keras
keras                     2.3.1                         0
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_0
keras-base                2.3.1                    py37_0
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                      py_1
```

Version 2 of Tensorflow
"Lib/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/api/_v2/keras/optimizers/schedules/**init**.py

```
 10 from . import schedules
```

Version 1.13.1 of Tensorflow

/tf11/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/keras/api/keras/optimizers/**init**.py

```
 # Optimizer classes.                                                                                                 
 22 from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import Adadelta                                                              
 23 from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import Adagrad                                                               
 24 from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import Adam                                                                  
 25 from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import Adamax                                                                
 26 from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import Nadam                                                                 
 27 from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import Optimizer                                                             
 28 from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import RMSprop                                                               
 29 from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import SGD                                                                   
 30                                                                                                                      
 31 # Auxiliary utils.                                                                                                   
 32 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order                                                                                 
 33 from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import deserialize                                                           
 34 from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import serialize                                                             
 35 from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import get
```

Comment: I tried the sequence and the first two ran fine. I can even import Adam, Adadelta from keras.optimizers, everything except schedules. As for the conda list, I got it exactly as it you mentioned. I can't just import schedules. Even from keras.optimizers import * works

Comment: I think your version of tensorflow does not have a schedule optimizer. I can find one in tensorflow 2.0, but not tensorflow 1.13.1 The full list of optimizers available to you are shown above